# PHP html logic error If condition works backwards

Tags: php, html

I have a form where I'm using a nested pair of foreach loops.  I can't figure out why the continue statement executes when the condition is false instead of true:  Here's the code I'm using

```
<?php $array =[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21] ; $i = 0;?> 
<?php foreach ($reservations as $reservation):  ?>

   <table class="tabsize1" style ="margin-top:0%;margin-bottom:0%;">
      <tbody>    
         <tr >
             <td class="nextsail"><?=$reservation["date"]     ?></td>
             <td class="nextsail"><?=$reservation["boat"]     ?></td>          
             <td class="nextsail"><?=$reservation["start_res"]?></td>   
             <td class="nextsail"><?=$reservation["end_res"]  ?></td> 
        </tr>    
     </tbody>
  </table>


  <?php  if($weather[$i]['cnt'] == 24) continue ; ?>  <!-- this works if i use != but $weather[$i]['cnt'] = 24  --> 

 <table >
   <tbody>    
      <tr >      
         <?php  foreach ($array as $value): ?>  
           <td> <?= $weather[$i][$value]['HOUR']?></td> 
         <?php endforeach ?> 
      </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>   

 <?php $i++; ?>       

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I think you miss understand what `continue` does. It means skip to next iteration of loop, not continue with the remainder of the loop

Comment: thanks, i read the manual 3 times and it just didn't sink in.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `;` after `endforeach`